# toggleClass on hyperlink not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm working with the following code:
http://jsfiddle.net/k5pnj4a4/8/ however my 'toggleClass' isn't working. Try the example in jsFiddle. Basically if I click the link, it goes red as expected but click again & it doesn't return to the original state :-(

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.filters a').on('click', function() {

        var data_filter = $(this).closest("a").data('filter');
        $(this).addClass('active'); 
        if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
            localStorage.setItem(data_filter,true);
        } else {
            localStorage.setItem(data_filter,false);
        }

    });

   $('.filters a').each(function(){
        var data_filter = $(this).closest("a").data('filter');
        var checked = localStorage.getItem(data_filter);
        if(checked){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="filters">

<h3 data-target="#colours_filters">Colour</h3>
<ul id="colours_filters">
    <li class="filter-option"><a href="#" data-tax="colours" data-filter=".tag-colours-black-2">Black</a></li>
    <li class="filter-option"><a href="#" data-tax="colours" data-filter=".tag-colours-blue">Blue</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Can someone provide assistance with this?

Thank you

Comment: not sure what you want exactly but i think you need something like this http://jsfiddle.net/k5pnj4a4/10/

Comment: There is no `toggleClass()` method called anywhere in the snippet you've provided.

Comment: You `addClass()` and then immediately after, test `hasClass()`. Your first `if` statement will *always* be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.filters a').on('click', function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
            $(this).removeClass("active");
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Many thanks - this is perfect! One odd glitch I've noticed is that one columns of list items is fully 'active' onLoad and the three other columns aren't active (unless they'd been active previously). Any ideas? I can provide a new jsfiddle if need be :-)